# How to connect two frames in Java?

Tags: java, jframe

I have three different frames:

- welcome.java
- Register.java
- LoginForm.java

If I click on Login button login page must open(i.e LoginForm.java) and if I click on Register button register page must open

```
//welcome.java
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class welcome extends JFrame
{

private JFrame frame;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                welcome window = new welcome();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public welcome() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JButton btnLogIn = new JButton("LOG IN");
    btnLogIn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        }
    });
    btnLogIn.setBounds(200, 69, 117, 25);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnLogIn);

    JButton btnRegister = new JButton("Register");
    btnRegister.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        }
    });
    btnRegister.setBounds(200, 138, 117, 25);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnRegister);

    JLabel lblNewToSvk = new JLabel("New to SVK Polytechnic ?");
    lblNewToSvk.setBounds(12, 143, 191, 15);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewToSvk);
}
}
```

.

```
  `//LoginForm.java
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class LoginForm extends JPanel implements ItemListener
{

/**
 * 
 */
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 private JFrame frame;
 private JTextField textField;
 private JPasswordField pwdJjh;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
             try {
                 LoginForm window = new LoginForm();
                 window.frame.setVisible(true);
             } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public LoginForm() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblStudentLogin = new JLabel("Login ");
    lblStudentLogin.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 30));
    lblStudentLogin.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lblStudentLogin.setBounds(94, 12, 265, 36);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblStudentLogin);

    JLabel lblUserName = new JLabel("USER NAME");
    lblUserName.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 15));
    lblUserName.setBounds(12, 74, 111, 15);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblUserName);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    textField.setBounds(141, 70, 160, 22);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("PASSWORD");
    lblPassword.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 15));
    lblPassword.setBounds(12, 116, 111, 15);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblPassword);

    pwdJjh = new JPasswordField();
    pwdJjh.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    pwdJjh.setBounds(141, 114, 160, 22);
    frame.getContentPane().add(pwdJjh);

    JLabel lblUserType = new JLabel("USER TYPE");
    lblUserType.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 15));
    lblUserType.setBounds(12, 154, 111, 15);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblUserType);

    JComboBox<String> cm = new JComboBox<String>();
    cm.setBounds(141, 148, 160, 24);
    cm.addItem("User");
    cm.addItem("Admin");
    cm.addItemListener(this);
    setLayout(null);
    frame.getContentPane().add(cm);


    JButton btnLogin = new JButton("Login ");
    btnLogin.setBounds(41, 199, 117, 25);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnLogin);

    JButton btnCancle = new JButton("Cancel");
    btnCancle.setBounds(209, 199, 117, 25);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnCancle);

 }

@Override
   public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

.

```
 //Register.java
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;


 public class Register {

 private JFrame frame;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Register window = new Register();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Register() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblRegisterForm = new JLabel("Register Form");
    lblRegisterForm.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
    lblRegisterForm.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 25));
    lblRegisterForm.setBounds(119, 12, 209, 25);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblRegisterForm);

    JLabel lblSelectTheUser = new JLabel("Select the user type");
    lblSelectTheUser.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 15));
    lblSelectTheUser.setBounds(22, 83, 192, 25);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblSelectTheUser);

    JComboBox cb1 = new JComboBox();
    cb1.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"Student", "Lecturer", "Office staff", "HOD"}));
    cb1.setBounds(213, 83, 151, 24);
    frame.getContentPane().add(cb1);
}

public void setVisible(boolean b) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void setTitle(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void setSize(int i, int j) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void setLocationRelativeTo(Object object) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void setDefaultCloseOperation(int exitOnClose) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
frame.setVisible(true);
```

to make a JFrame (form) visible.